# Is there any better way of writing interfaces if all the items are string in object?

Tags: typescript

I have a interface like this:

```
interface companyInfoProps {
  account: {
    merchantName: string;
    loginMailAddress: string;
    loginPhone: string;
    vknTcknNumber: string;
    invoiceAddress: string;
  };
  district: string;
  city: string;
}
```

As you can see every items in the object are string type. Is there any better way to write this interface? Or I just have to write :string next to every element?

Comment: Better by what metric? I see no problem with that notation.

Comment: "Or I just have to write :string next to every element?" makes it very clear what I mean by better.

Comment: Not really. It describes what you want, but not why it is better. What metric/criteria makes `merchantName` better than `merchantName: string`?

Comment: For example if I was able to write account: string{merchantName;loginMailAddress;loginPhone;
vknTcknNumber;invoiceAddress;} is a better way for me since it does the same thing with less code.

Comment: Or some way which tells typescript that every element in this object will be string. So that I do not have to write :string in every element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) utility type:

> Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property values are Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

Second argument of `Record` will be applied to each key.

```js
type AccountKeys =
    | 'merchantName'
    | 'loginMailAddress'
    | 'loginPhone'
    | 'vknTcknNumber'
    | 'invoiceAddress'

interface CompanyInfoProps {
    account: Record<AccountKeys, string>;
    district: string;
    city: string;
}
```

Please keep in mind, that your example is perfectly valid.
I can't say that my approach is better in some way. It just a different approach.

I think it worth reading about: [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)